# Why do protanopes see yellow and not green?

Tags: human-genetics, vision, receptor

Why can protanopes see yellow but not green when the relative absorbance of these two colour waves by the m cone can be identical?

Comment: What makes you think that "protanopes see yellow and not green"?

Comment: Only because the colour wheels that I see keep referring to shades of yellow for what they can see

Comment: How else should they display the color wheel so you can view it?

Comment: Are you saying that green could be substituted for yellow and that it doesn't matter? I was probably overthinking it because I know blue-green and red cones are involved in green colour vision, so I thought the brain would default to yellow because that only requires two cones or because the green cone can still "pick up" yellow waves.

Comment: Yellow makes some sense from the perspective of opponent-process theory of color determination, see e.g. this answer: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/27486/27148 but really someone who is "red-green colorblind" sees all wavelengths, from red through blue, it's just that red and green can't be differentiated easily (especially in different shades).

Comment: Thanks, @BryanKrause, for your perspective. I will look deeper into what the resource you have linked to provides.